# How to force digit-only matInput to start with a specific number?

Tags: angular, regex

I want to have an input that accepts numbers only, and start with a specific number.
To force the input to start with a number from a local variable, I tried, with no success yet, the following:

```
<input matInput autocomplete="off" formControlName="start" minlength="3" maxlength="3"
                        type="text" (input)=forceStart($event)>
```

In the `.ts` file:

```
starter: number = 4;
forceStart(e) {
 e.value = e.value.replace('/[^' + this.starter + '][^0-9]/g', '');
}
```

How to force the input to start with the starter variable?

**EDIT1**

The reason of not using `type="number"` is to avoid the auto up/down arrows to increment/decrement the value.

**EDIT2**

I used a function instead of inline javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `input` of type `number`, this reduces the risk of non-digit characters in the input and unecessary validators. To hide the arrows follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp) w3schools tutorial.

---

**Solution 1** - Custom Validator with error message

In your components HTML would look like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="start">
        <mat-error *ngIf="(form.controls['start'].touched 
            || form.controls['start'].dirty)
            && !form.controls['start'].valid
            && form.controls['start'].hasError('numberStartingWith')">
            Number must start with {{starter}}
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

In your components TS, you want to use a reactive form with a custom async validator:

```js
private starter: number = 4;

public form = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(undefined, {
        asyncValidators: numberStartingWith(this.starter),
        updateOn: 'change'
    })
})
```

In a separate file or outside the components class create the following function:

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export const numberStartingWith = (starter: number): ValidatorFn => {
    return (c: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> =>
        new RegExp(`^${starter}`).test(c.value) ? 
            of(null) : 
            of({numberStartingWith: {value: c.value}})
}
```

Edit: Updated the solution - This way the user could type in any number at first, but will see an error message. i.e.

- user types `4` in first place, no error message displayed
- user types `3` in first place, error message will be displayed
- user corrects `3` in first place to `4`, error message will disappear

---

**Solution 2** - using `matPrefix`

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="start">
    <div matPrefix>{{starter}}</div>
</mat-form-field>
```

The `matPrefix` will display the starter number but won't be used in validation or such. On form submition you'd need to add the starter value programmatically in your typescript code.

---

**Please Note**: Never change a users input in the UI. It makes the UI/UX unclear to the user and might cause frustration. Use validators where possible or edit the values before submition.

Comment: This did not work for me, but if it worked as validator for start, that is not what I want, I want to prevent the user of typing any number that does not start with the pre-defined digit. thank you for efforts.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, if ``starter`` is set, the number entered into the input field is only allowed to start with it, for example, ``4``. Meaning that only values like ``40``, ``47``, ``485``, etc. are allowed?

Comment: that is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following file input.ts:

```
var starter: number = 4;
var re = new RegExp('[^'+starter+']{1}[0-9]{2}|[^0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1}[^0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}[^0-9]{1}');

function repl(input: string) {
  return input.replace(re, '');
}
```

compile:

tsc input.ts

The test html file is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="input.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
                <form>
                        <input matInput autocomplete="off" formControlName="start" minlength="3" maxlength="3" type="text" oninput="this.value=repl(this.value);">
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try it!

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, I have just figured this out..

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in two steps:

1-Put the variable inside a regex:

```
starter: string = '4';
regex = new RegExp("^" + this.starter + "{1}[0-9]{0,2}$");
```

2-Use the regex to ensure the value is matching the pattern, otherwise remove the last character.

```
forceStart(e) {
if (this.regex.test(e.srcElement.value)) {
}
else {
  e.srcElement.value = e.srcElement.value.slice(0, -1);
}
```